# d3v4 Nesting force graphs

Tags: d3.js

I have a force directed graph in d3v4 and I'd like to situate another, smaller force graph around each node.

Here is an example of what I want to do, but this is in v3. I basically tried to take this pattern from there, and it didn't work. http://bl.ocks.org/djjupa/5655723

I thought to accomplish that by creating a new one inside `node.each`, but that doesn't appear to be working.

Here's my code to make the new node -- it appears to be the same as the code that is successfully instantiating the first forcegraph, but this is in a d3.each function on the d3 node group.

When I inspect the childnodes by console.logging them in the tick function,  I see that it has a single element array _groups that has a 3 element array with 3 undefined elements in it. Hmmm - could that be the problem?

```
135       console.log('instantiateChildForceGraph', parent, ix)
136 
137       let subFg = d3.select(this)
138      
139       parent.tokens.fixed = true
140       parent.tokens.x = 0
141       parent.tokens.y = 0
142  
143       let icon_size = 16
144 
145       let childNodes = parent.tokens.children
146 
147       let childSimulation = d3.forceSimulation()
148         .force('collide', d3.forceCollide( (d) => { return 150 }).iterations(16))
149         .force('center', d3.forceCenter(window.innerWidth/2, window.innerHeight/2))
150         .force('link', d3.forceLink()
151           .id((d) => { return d.index + 1 })
152           .distance(200)
153           .strength(1))
154         .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody())
155         .force('x', d3.forceX())
156         .force('y', d3.forceY())
157         .alphaTarget(1)
158 
159       let childNode = subFg.selectAll('.token')
160         .data(childNodes, (d) => { return d.id })
161 
162       let childNodeEnter = childNode
163         .enter()
164           .append('g')
165           .attr('class', 'token-node-' + parent.id )
166           .attr('transform', (d) => { return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')' })
167 
168       childNodeEnter
169           .append('circle')
170             .attr('class', (d) => { return  'token token-' + d.source })
171             .attr('r', 5)
172             .style('fill', 'black')
173             .style('stroke', 'black')
174 
175       childNode.exit().remove()
176 
177       // let childNode = subFg.select('g.token-node-' + parent.id)
178       //   .selectAll('.token')
179       //   .data(childNodes, (d) => { return d.id })
180       //   .enter()
181       //       .attr('transform', (d) => { console.log('d', d); return 'translate(' + d.x ? d.x : 0 + ',' + d.y ? d.y : 0  + ')' })
182       //   .exit()
183       //     .remove()
184 
185       console.log('childSimulation', childSimulation)
186       console.log('childNodes', childNodes)
187 
188       console.log('no')
189       childSimulation.nodes(childNodes)
190       childSimulation.force('link').links()
191       childSimulation.on('tick', function(d) {
192         console.log('childnode', childNode)
193         childNode.attr('transform', (d) => { return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')' })
194       })
195     }
196
```

Answer (score -2):

So upon inspecting `childNode` I saw this particular code was actually returning 3 elements of undefined. So I had to refine the selection process for `childNode` to select the root `<g>` element of these sub nodes.

But that wasn't the only problem - I did that quickly after making these posts as a matter of fact.

But there was another problem that was much more elusive. Everything was working out, but I couldn't see the sub force animation in the browser.

It turns out that is because, probably somehow since it was a nested force graph, it was animating it with an offset of about 700 pixels, so I simply couldn't see it. That was solved by simply changing the transform function to negate the distance of the offset.